# How to compare vertx.buffer and java.io.String

Tags: java, vert.x

I want to run the function as the accompanying source to receive input a specific string from the client. However, this does not work.

How you can operate it? Please help me!

```
public class Server {
private Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions().setWorkerPoolSize(1024));
private NetServer server = vertx.createNetServer();

public void start(int port){

    server.connectHandler(socket -> {
        socket.handler(buffer -> {
            System.out.println("I received some bytes: " + buffer.length());

            if(buffer.equals(Buffer.buffer().appendString("STOP!"))){
                socket.write(Buffer.buffer().appendString("The server will be shut down."));
                this.stop();
            }
        });
    });

    server.listen(port, "localhost", res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            System.out.println("Server is now listening!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to bind!");
        }
    });
}


public void stop(){
    server.close(res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            System.out.println("Server is now closed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("close failed");
        }
    });
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying `buffer.toString().equals("STOP!")` or  `new String(buffer.getBytes).equals("STOP")`?

Comment: @zella I tried, but the result seems to be a failed attempt.

Comment: How i see in http://tutorials.jenkov.com/vert.x/tcp-server.html  string from buffer takes as `String data = inBuffer.getString(0, inBuffer.length());`

Comment: @zella Thank you. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you get this to work in this specific situation, this won't work the way you think it does generally.

TCP does not have a logical notion of "messages" like you're imagining it does. It is more of a stream, which `vertx` is conveniently presenting chunks of to you in terms of bytes.

Compare character by character instead, since the underlying `netty ByteBuf` objects for both buffers may be views of larger pieces of memory and therefore causing the comparison to fail. But consider using web sockets, if your client situation will allow you to, since it will be much easier for you to wrap your mind around.